# The colour of the box is different in IE9?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

The box is showing the right colour in chrome,safari and firefox. But in IE the box colour is yellow/gold. See the pictures below for the problem I am facing.

How to fix this?

Firefox:[image]

IE9:[image]

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/c7czs/) (open this example in IE)

HTML CODE:

```
<div id="container105">
        <div class="bubbleouter">
            <div class="bubbleinner"><CENTER><BOLD>VUL KOSTENLOOS DE OFFERTE IN EN WIJ BEREKEN DE PRIJS VAN UW SPECIFIEKE RIT<BOLD></CENTER></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS CODE:

```
}
.bubbleouter {
    position:relative;
    padding:3px;
    margin:0;
        width:280px;
        z-index:99;
        background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#272727), to(#222222));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #272727, #222222);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #272727, #222222);


    /* css3 */
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    border-radius:10px;
}

.bubbleouter:after {
    content:"";
    display:block; /* reduce the damage in FF3.0 */
    position:absolute;
    top:-13px; /* value = - border-top-width - border-bottom-width */
    left:50%; /* controls horizontal position */
        margin:0 0 0 -18px;
    width:0;
    height:0;
        z-index:99;
    border-width:0 18px 14px; /* vary these values to change the angle of the vertex */
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#222222 transparent;
}

.bubbleinner {
    position:relative;
    padding:15px;
    margin:0;
    color:#eee;
        text-align:center;
        z-index:100;
    text-shadow:0px -1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    background:#f3961c; /* default background for browsers without gradient support */
        border-top:1px solid #666666;

    /* css3 */
    -moz-border-radius:7px;
    -webkit-border-radius:7px;
    border-radius:7px;
    /* NOTE: webkit gradient implementation is not as per spec */
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#666666), to(#444444));
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #666666, #444444);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #666666, #444444);
}



.bubbleinner:after {
    content:"";
    display:block; /* reduce the damage in FF3.0 */
    position:absolute;
    top:-13px; /* value = - border-top-width - border-bottom-width */
    left:50%; /* controls horizontal position */
        margin:0 0 0 -16px;
    width:0;
    height:0;
        z-index:99;
    border-width:0 16px 12px; /* vary these values to change the angle of the vertex */
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#666666 transparent;
}
```

Comment: Off topic: `<BOLD>` is not a valid HTML tag. And `<CENTER>` is valid but is deprecated. You should be using CSS instead for both of these; with `font-weight:bold` and `text-align:center`.

Comment: Please see my answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15089230/1317805. The answer you accepted suggests using a fixed colour for IE9, but IE9 supports gradient just fine (as does IE6, 7 and 8!) using `filter`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have specified that color for browsers without gradient support:

```
background:#f3961c; /* default background for browsers without gradient support */
```

Change that to a color that works with your design:

```
background:#666; /* default background for browsers without gradient support */
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer was accepted. IE9 DOES support gradients. See my answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15089230/1317805

Comment: @JamesDonnelly: Yes, you can also add support for gradients for a number of browsers, but this fixes the main problem, i.e. the orange background.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is the background attributes:

```
background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#272727), to(#222222));
background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #272727, #222222);
background:-o-linear-gradient(top, #272727, #222222);
```

`-webkit-*` targets webkit browsers (which IE isn't).
`-moz-*` targets Mozilla Firefox.
`-o-*` targets Opera.

If you want to use gradient backgrounds across all supporting browsers, this is a pretty awesome resource: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Using that with your colours, for `.bubbleouter` you'd want:

```
background: #272727; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #272727 0%, #222222 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#272727), color-stop(100%,#222222)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #272727 0%,#222222 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #272727 0%,#222222 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #272727 0%,#222222 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #272727 0%,#222222 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#272727', endColorstr='#222222',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

...and for `bubbleinner` you'd want:

```
background: #666666; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #666666 0%, #444444 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#666666), color-stop(100%,#444444)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #666666 0%,#444444 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #666666 0%,#444444 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #666666 0%,#444444 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #666666 0%,#444444 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#666666', endColorstr='#444444',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

Comment: the `filter` styles are buggy and awkward to use. If you must do gradients in IE, use CSS3Pie.

Comment: @SDC swings and roundabouts. CSS3Pie is slow.

Comment: @Blowsie - In my experience, CSS3Pie has acceptable performance for most use cases. If you're worried about performance, just drop the gradient entirely for IE9. The bugs with `filter` are worse.

Comment: @SDC: `filter` works without JavaScript. I've not had any issues using `filter` before in IE, could you give an example of a bug?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly true but its uses directX both have performance considerations but for me `filter` or no support is the way to go

Comment: @JamesDonnelly an example is having gradients and rounded corners at the same time

Comment: @JamesDonnelly - Vlad mentioned on in his answer; broken support for border radius (which is required for the question). There are other more subtle bugs as well related to it being an activeX control. Re having JS turned off... well, I haven't seen a single user doing that in the real world in several years. Not saying it doesn't happen, but if you've got a sensible plain colour fallback colour for the background, it really shouldn't matter anyway.

Answer (score 3):

add the following line before the gradient declarations:

```
background : #272727;
```

The bug happens because IE does not support gradients. 
Don't use filters like

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#272727', endColorstr='#222222',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
```

These filters don't respect drop-shadows and border radius.

Answer (score 1):

IE9 does not support CSS gradients, so you are seeing the default background colour for the box after the gradients have been ignored.

The easiest answer is to give a more sensible default `background` style, so that browsers that don't support gradients will get a colour that comes close to matching what you want.

If you do want to support gradients in IE, you could use the IE proprietary `filter` style to do it, but I would avoid this if possible as the syntax is horrible and the end result can be buggy (especially when used in conjunction with other CSS3 styles).

A better solution would be to use the [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/) library to patch IE to add support for CSS3 style gradients. CSS3Pie works in all versions of IE (6-9), and adds gradients to IE9, and gradients, box shadow and border radius to IE 6-8. This will allow you to support IE9 properly with your gradients.

Hope that helps.